# Como carregar conteúdo de arquivo m3u em uma lista no php

Tags: php, html

A ideia é ter um campo `input` onde o usuário coloca o link do `m3u` e ao aperta o botão a lista de canais que está nesse arquivo `m3u` seja mostrada abaixo em uma tabela.

Os campos que conte nesse arquivo `m3u` são: 
    `tvg-logo - tvg-name -`

A estrutura é basicamente assim:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="BBB 18 -Aquecimento" tvg-logo="https://s9.postimg.org/4c14egx5b/big_Welcome_Pic_4-300x169.png" group-title="Canais Globo",BBB 18 -Aquecimento
http://infinity.quor8.com:8000/live/wesleybr/mxViBCIK05/12664.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Globo RJ FHD" tvg-logo="http://i.imgur.com/NSHvLCe.png" group-title="Canais Globo",Globo RJ FHD
http://infinity.quor8.com:8000/live/wesleybr/mxViBCIK05/12665.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Globo RJ" tvg-name="Globo RJ HD" tvg-logo="http://i.imgur.com/NSHvLCe.png" group-title="Canais Globo",Globo RJ HD
http://infinity.quor8.com:8000/live/wesleybr/mxViBCIK05/1586.ts
```

O link é assim:

```
http://Infinity.quor8.com:8000/get.php?
username=NOME-DO-USUARIO&password=SENHA-DO-USUARIO&type=m3u_plus&output=ts
```

A ideia como eu disse é deixar o link acima em um campo, gerar abaixo uma tabela com a logo, nome e link dos canais.

Eu tentei aqui de diversas formas, mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Se possível edite sua pergunta clicando em [edit] e poste o código que você fez até o momento.

Comment: André, tenta usar esse pacote, pelo que vi ele já faz todo o "mapeamento" das informações da lista https://packagist.org/packages/chrisyue/php-m3u8